# new locale in flash builder (czech)

Tags: apache-flex, localization, flash-builder

is any site where can i get sdk locale files for flash builder? i need czech locale
thanks for help

Comment: in my opinion. It will be difficult to use official documentation about almost any IDE, in a case when you switch to not English locale.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Czech locale isn't supported out of the box by the vendor and AFAIK there is no resources with any additional third party locales. So the only way for you is using `copylocale` utility as described [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f2d.html) and then replacing English messages you needed with Czech.